# How do I interpret this log linear regression coefficient?

Tags: regression

Correction on previous post.

I have a log linear regression model where the dependent variable is logged and an independent variable is linear. The slope coefficient for a key independent variable is negative: -.0564. Not sure how to interpret.

Do I use the absolute value of .0564 and then turn it into a negative like this: ((exp.(.0564)-1) * 100 = -5.80)

OR

Do I plug in the negative coefficient like this: ((exp.(-.0564)-1) * 100 = -5.48)

In other words, do I use the absolute figure and then turn that into a negative or do I plug in the negative coefficient? As you can see they produce 2 different answers.

Comment: george, you can comment on your preceding question if you need further clarification or if you want to add details. You could then vote to reopen your post rather than reposting the same question. Please, tell us what's not clear with the possible duplicate, and we'll merge this question with your other one.